# Dropzonejs rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, dropzone.js

I have a problem with preview pictures in dropzonejs. When I reload my page, all photos from server load to this dropzone. Some photos don't load fully. How can I fix this bug.

[click here to see my dropzone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVfKn.jpg)

And there is my js code.

```
Dropzone.options.mydropzone = {
  paramName: "upload[image]",
  maxFilesize: 2,
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  thumbnailWidth: 300,
  thumbnailHeight: 300,
  success: function(file, response) {
    $(file.previewElement).find('.dz-remove').attr('id', response.uploadId);
    $(file.previewElement).addClass('dz-success');
  },
  removedfile: function(file) {
var id = $(file.previewTemplate).find('.dz-remove').attr('id');

$.ajax ({
  type: 'DELETE',
  url: "/uploads/" + id,
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data.message);
  }
});

var previewElement;
return (previewElement = file.previewElement) != null ? (previewElement.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement)) : (void 0);
  },

  init: function() {
    var me = this;
    $.get("<%= Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.list_uploads_path %>",
function(data){
      $.each(data.images, function(key, value){
        if(data.images != undefined && data.images.length > 0) {
          me.emit("addedfile", value);
          me.emit("thumbnail", value, value.src);
          me.emit("complete", value);

      $(value._removeLink).attr("id", value.id);
    }
  });
});
```

}
};